# Ajax not supported for viewscope in jsf

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, view-scope

I am new to jsf. I had trouble in working in ajax and viewscope bean.

Here is my code:

### index.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    <h:form>

        <h:inputText id ="text" value="#{bean2.str1}" />
        <h:inputText id ="text2" value="#{bean2.str1}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Test">
            <f:ajax execute="text" render="text2"/>
        </h:commandButton>

        <h:commandButton value="Home" action="home"/>
    </h:form>        
</h:body>
</html>
```

### Bean2.java

```
package com.hem.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean2 implements Serializable {

public String str1;

public String getStr1() 
{
    return str1;
}
public void setStr1(String str) 
{
    str1 = str;
}
}
```

The page shows up with 2 inputboxes and a command Button "Test".
When I enter value in the first inputbox and click Test nothing happens (no error either).

But when In I make the bean as Sessionscoped It works fine.

Please guide me through this.

Comment: Are you implying that it works when you remove `<f:ajax>`? If not, then please revise your title.

Comment: Its working really fine for me with same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work fine with `@ViewScoped`.. However, you can change the value of the `execute` attribute's value by: `@form` in order to submit all the form :

```
<h:form>

    <h:inputText id ="text" value="#{bean2.str1}" /><br />
    <h:outputText id ="text2" value="#{bean2.str1}" /><br />
    <h:commandButton value="Test">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="text2"/>
    </h:commandButton>

    <h:commandButton value="Home" action="home"/>
</h:form>
```

Also, you had better make the result shows in a `<h:outputText />` tag component rather than another `<h:inputText />`.

Comment: In other words, you're confirming that this doesn't solve OP's concrete problem at all?

Comment: Not sure, because i tried this example and it runs fine. Let's wait the reaction's question owner.

Comment: I feel there is some problem with net beans. When I tried my original program it worked nicely after trying your changes. But when I restarted NetBeans my original program did not work. 

So I copied the war file to the webapps folder of tomcat 6 and ran the program(original). It worked fine with execute="text".

Any way Thanks a lot.